# How can someone set Emacs / Spacemacs to prefer OTF font over TTF font when both are available?

Tags: spacemacs, fonts

Recently the [nixos fira-code package](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/68396) added both the otf and ttf fonts and Emacs/Spacemacs isn't quite happy with the ttf ones.

How could I tell spacemacs to prefer OTF over TTF when both are available for the same typeface / font?

TTF:
[image]

OTF(*):
[image]

(*) This only works because the system default font is Fira Code Retina and it just happens to be what I want. However it is not because of writing it there.

Comment: The TTF case indicates either a bug in the font or a bug in Emacs (or the underlying font-handling libraries it uses), so please report this as a bug!

Comment: Gedit / other applications in my system behave correctly so should the bug report be filled with Emacs or Spacemacs?

Comment: It seems unlikely that this problem can be linked to a faulty config, so it's likely on the Emacs side, but in any case it should be very easy to try and reproduce the bug in Emacs beforehand to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for the help, will do that when I get home.